# Run 12.10 and 12.04 off same home partition

Tags: 12.04, installation, 12.10, partitioning

This is a weird one and I apologize if this is a duplicate question, I looked but couldn't find a answer.  I upgraded to 12.10 and it works with the side that I have to use the open ati driver cause my card isn't supported anymore so I want to install 12.04 along side 12.10 but use the same home partition.  Is this safe or even advisable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tried the same before with Ubuntu and Kubuntu. Trust me, this is not a good idea. Especially if you have the same applications installed in both versions. Also, it leads to a lot of permission issues. Better to have different /home partitions. You can of course share the same swap and data drives, not home. I personally wouldn't recommend that. Too many hassles...